# VectorFieldPlot Assumptions - restricted domain

Tags: plotting, assumptions

I would like to plot the 2-D vector field:

```
VectorFieldPlot[{ x/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], y/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]}, {x, -5,  5}, {y, -5, 5} ]
```

but I encounter zero division at the origin. How to cast out the point {0,0}? I tried the Assumptions -> x <> 0 && y <> 0, but the string Assumptions is red and seems that it isn't available for VectorFieldPlot.

Furthermore, for another vector field, I would need to cast out the semi-line "(x,0), x in ( - infininty, 0 >".

To summarize: the question is how to restrict the (plot) domain of a vector field?

Could you help?

Thank you and wish you a nice day

marfi

Comment: Stackexchange etiquette: If your problem is solved, you should consider accepting the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

You want the `RegionFunction` parameter.  This should be a raw Function object that returns `True` in the region that you *do* want plotted.  Examples:

```
VectorPlot[{x/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], y/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5},
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x^2 + y^2 > (0.1)^2]]
```

[image: Vector plot with origin excised]

```
VectorPlot[{x/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], y/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5},     
 RegionFunction ->  Function[{x, y}, (y^2 > (0.1)^2) || (x > 0.1)]]
```

[image: Vector plot with negative x-axis excised]

Answer (score 1):

Use `VectorPlot` instead.

```
VectorPlot[{x/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], y/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

[image: vectorplot]